# Is the following formula a tautology?

Tags: logic

In order to find out whether this formula is a tautology, I'm creating a semantic tree for its negation. If all of the branches are a contradiction then the formula is a tautology.

Formula: !(A => B) <=> (!B => !A).

This is how I do it: !(!(A => B) <=> (!B => !A))

|=|

!(( (A ∧ !B) => (B ∨ !A) ) ∧ ( (B ∨ !A) => (A ∧ !B) ))

|=|

(A ∧ !B) ∨ (!A ∨ B).

This is how my semantic tree looks like:

A

/    |    \

!A    B    !B

Which in the semantic tree is a contradiction, so the formula is a tautology. I was drawing the tree the wrong way, now I clearly see it.

Comment: The formula is never true. The statement on the right is equivalent to $A\implies B$ which is the negation of the statement on the left.

Comment: The formula is not a *tautology*, because $(A \to B) \equiv (\lnot B \to \lnot A)$.

Comment: But the last step in your tree is **not** a contradicition : with a valuation $v$ such that $v(A)=$ **t** and $v(B)=$ **f** the formula is *satisfied*. Thus, the tree does not close and this proves that the formula is **not** taut.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA hello, I've added how I thought the semantic tree should look like and better explanation. I still don't see how this semantic tree is not a contradiction (and therefore the formula tautology)? Now I see that I draw it the wrong way...

Comment: You have a disjunction; thus, two branches : the left one for $(A \land \lnot B)$ and the right one for $(\lnot A \lor B)$. No way to find a contradiction...

Answer (score 0):

I was drawing the tree the wrong way, the semantic three is neither contradiction nor tautology, so the formula is neither.

Comment: This is not an answer...